# Dictionary extension to return a combined dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to extend Swift's dictionary class in the following manner:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func merge<K, V>(dict: [K:V]) -> Dictionary<K, V> {
        var combinedDict: [K:V] = [:]
        for (k, v) in self {
            combinedDict[k] = v
        }

        for (k, v) in dict {
            combinedDict[k] = v
        }

        return combinedDict
    }



}
```

The first for loop gives me the error: "Cannot subscript a value of type '[K:V]' with an index of type 'Key'" but the second for loop is fine. I even commented out the first one to check and the second still works. Anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting `self` and `dict` to have the same Key/Value types?

Comment: yea I'll be using this method for two dictionaries of the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary type already defines `Key` and `Value` as generic variables, so `K` and `V` are not required (and cause the problem).

```
extension Dictionary {
    func merge(dict: [Key : Value]) -> [Key : Value] {
        var combinedDict = self

        for (k, v) in dict {
            combinedDict[k] = v
        }

        return combinedDict
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary's generic placeholder types are called Key and Value and you have to keep those names; you cannot arbitrarily rename them K and V.

Here's the implementation I use:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func addEntriesFromDictionary(d:[Key:Value]) { // generic types
        for (k,v) in d {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code.

```
   extension Dictionary {
        func merge(other: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
            var ret: [Key: Value] = self
            for (key, value) in other {
                ret[key] = value
            }
            return ret
        }
    }
```